# Javascript error from numeral.js when minified

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

I am getting this javascript error from [numeral.js (1.5.3)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/master/numeral.js) when our js files are minified.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
```

Since it's minified I am not exactly sure on what line the error is, but when I click on the error message in chrome, the cursor goes here, so I am guessing this is the 'length' thats failing.

```
..... A=A.split(".")[1].length?o[p].delimiters.decimal+A.split(".")[1]:"".....
```

This is where the call to numeral.js is made.

```
        var percentage = '3.98385103884072E-03';
        var formattedPct = numeral(Math.abs(percentage)).format('0.0000');
```

It works fine when the files are not minified. Any idea where should I look into?

Thanks.

Comment: What minifier are you using?

Comment: We are using Yui js minifier

Comment: Clearly your minifier has screwed it up for you. Try [a](http://jscompress.com/) [different](http://javascriptcompressor.com/) [one](http://javascript-minifier.com/).

Comment: I can confirm @ArtOfCode answer. I use numeraljs from bower (it comes with a minified version as well) and I just tested your code, and it works good!